# Make images scale to parent div only when larger, all while using an explicit max-width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I can make an image scale responsively to a parent div on smaller screens but still limit to an explicit max width:

```
img {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, if the image is smaller than the parent div, it is still stretched to fill the div.

Is there a way to have it scale to 100% only when it is larger and maintain its original dimensions when it is smaller, without knowing the image's dimensions beforehand?

Answer (score 16):

You can set the image's max-width: 100%; which would limit its size only if it's bigger than its parent.

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LMEwC/

Comment: height is defaulted to auto if not explicitly set.

Comment: Sorry. An additional constraint: I already have an explicit max pixel width. I've edited the question again.

Comment: Since you need the 500px; you could wrap the image: <div class="img-wrap"><img /></div> where the img CSS attributes you currently have can be changed to .img-wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/LMEwC/

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using Bootstrap (version 3.x, perhaps other versions as well) you can also use

```
class='img-responsive'
```

on your `<img>` tag to resize it to the parent element's size.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the image inside a div and apply these styles:

```
<div><img></div>

div{max-width: 500px}
img{max-width: 100%}
```

example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLCvZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) to the css.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    min-width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to specify the constraint that I don't know the image's dimensions beforehand. The question has been edited.

Comment: There's no way to do this only using css then. You can grab the initial size with JS, then apply that based on screen size, but obviously that's not a css route.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to find the respective width/height of picture and div and then resize the image to the fit the div.

You can use this code to find the height, create this function.

```
function getHeight(id)
{
return document.getElementById("id").offsetHeight; // Change to .offsetWidth to gain width :)
}
```

call the function like this:

```
function resize()
{
var imgHeight = getHeight("img");
var divHeight = getHeight("div");

//Then ask:

    if(imgHeight > divHeight)
    {
    pic = document.getElementById("img");
    pic.style.height = divHeight;
    }
}
```

Now you need some action to call the functions,  might work? or some onclick event? Depends on how you are using this image.

I hope this helps. It SHOULD do the job.

NB: It has come to my attention that used with spesific types of elements Google Chrome simply ignores max/min-width, when width is present (CSS)! But not always.