# Responsively resize an image using CSS3, relative to the width of its parent element, without exceeding its original size

Tags: html, css, web

I started building a Tribute page on CodePen.io, followed the user stories and got 9 out of 10 of the tests. I've been stuck on resizing the image using CSS3. I googled, tried the answers but none worked for me.
The CSS code is :

```
#img-div {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   width: 100%;
}

img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
}
```

Here is the link to the CodePen page https://codepen.io/dansia/pen/NWxNMJP look at it and help me solve this challenge.

Comment: If you want to make the image responsive with a maximum width then you have to define both `width` and `maximum-width` on the `img` element. E.G., `img { width: 100%; maximum-width: 330px }`

Comment: No you don't need both.  you only need `max-width` and the image will grow to its natural width as max. Look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/huygs61p/).  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS image max-width set to original image size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197730/css-image-max-width-set-to-original-image-size)

Answer (score 3):

I used this to get the image to the center and to make it relative to the width of the parent.

```
#image {
    display: block;
      
    max-width: 100%;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    
    margin-right: auto;
    
}
```

You can also use `width: 100%;` to make the image bigger so it's in the center of the page, but that way you just fool the program, which is not fair.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
#image {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-width:500px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call it from your div?

```
#img-div {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   width: 100%;
}

#img-div img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
}

<div id=“img-div”>
 <img href=“something”/>
</div>
```

Comment: Then if you want your picture to resize make your width smaller but in image container which is #img-div.

Answer (score 0):

I added *margin-left (auto)*, *margin-right (auto)* and *display (block)* to *img* element and it worked for me. Finally got the **10/10**.

The whole code is then :

```
#img-div {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
  **margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;**
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the command

```
    image { 
   max-width: 100%; 
   height: auto;
}
```

is usually enough. but the way that codepin tests for the code is searching for both **width** and **max-width**

however, people were saying that you should specify max-width to 330. I simply didn't know how to acquire the information that this image has this width so I had to figure out another way. so here it is (and it passed the test):

```
  #img-div{
  background-color: white;
}

  #image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  }
```

you can check it in my codepin project here: https://codepen.io/asserelfeki/pen/LYNOEVJ

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the same project.

```
#img-div {
    margin: auto;
    width: 97%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#image {
    max-width: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Why 90%? As for the challenge, we don't want the image to take the full width of the container.
After adding these properties, no matter how much I resize my page, the image will not exceed the container, it will be responsive

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did

```
 #img-div {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
  **margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#img-div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of how your code answers the question, as code-only answers are less useful. Especially when there are other, previous answers, it is good to explain how your answer differs from or improves on the others.

Comment: You can even add comments to your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for your reference

```
img
{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution:

```
#image {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#img-div{  
  width: 50%; <!--depends on the image resolution and its appearance in the page-->
  background: white;
  margin: auto; <!--centering the image-->
  padding: 15px;
}

#image{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's generally useful to add some context around the code to make this answer more helpful.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113056/make-images-scale-to-parent-div-only-when-larger-all-while-using-an-explicit-ma

Answer (score -2):

This link contains what you should need:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/tribute-page-responsively-resize-img-relative-to-parent-element/203586

Code in case link doesn't help:

```
#image {
max-width: 250px; <!--Base width-->
width: 100%; <--Size according to parent use percentage-->
display: block;
margin: auto; <!-- center the image -->
```

}

Comment: This belongs in a comment.  It does not specifically resolve his issue.

Comment: @ShivanshTheAmazing thank you for sharing the link. I copied a code there that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

try this i thing this is help ful for you....

```
@media (min-width:500px) {
  /*Class name*/ {
    /*properties*/
  }
}
@media (max-width:499px) {
  /*Class name*/ {
    /*properties*/
  }
}
```